# Java KeyListener is not working

Tags: java, event-handling

I've just managed to get KeyListener to work in an empty application, but then I tried to implement it in my application and it simply doesn't work, no matter how much I enter keys!

A friend told me it's because I have buttons (JButton) on the application (and I implement the actionPerformed method,) can anyone explain to me why this is  happening (and how to fix it) ?

EDIT:-
Yes, the problem is about focus, and I found the solution in some forums, and the solution is very simple. It`s by adding:
setFocusable(true); after, setVisible(true); in the class that extends JFrame.

Comment: I don`t know what to add, as the code is so big to fit here!

Comment: It`s a calculator. I have a class extending JFrame with buttons added on it (from 1 to 9,) I also have a textfield added. Then I`m handling the events caused by the number buttons by implementing the ActionPerformed method of the ActionListener interface.

Comment: Simplify the code to something that you can post. In the process, you will either find the problem yourself, or come to a point where someone can actually help you.

Comment: I will do that, but the main question is: Is there any interference between the listening to JButtons and Listening to keys (by adding the frame to listeners list) ?

Comment: @w4j3d no simply, but go for actionListener

Comment: If you can't simplify the code then at least provide a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wich component are you adding the KeyListener? i think that if you want to listen the KeyEvents in the whole calculator you must add it to the Container in wich the buttons are.

But i belive that only the component who has the focus recive the KeyEvents, so that i dont know if the container can has the focus or if the events are promoted to their parent if the focus is on the buttons of the calculator.

You can solve this adding a keyListener to the container doing the stuff (printing the characters i suposse), and to the buttons and the textfield, promoting the event to it's container